# custom maven GWT build fails on openshift

Tags: maven, gwt, jenkins, openshift

On RedHat OpenShift I have created a jenkins build server. To get it working for my custom build I've changed the **config.xml** to have `numExecutors=1`. Then I added a maven gwt project to build. The build fails because it can not create the user preferences directory. See this log snippet.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0-rc2:compile (default) @ web ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [de.hpfsc.parent]
[ERROR] Apr 09, 2014 2:06:42 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
[ERROR] WARNING: Couldn't create user preferences directory. User preferences are unusable.
[ERROR] Apr 09, 2014 2:06:42 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
[ERROR] WARNING: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

To test the correct working of simple maven builds I created a new jenkins project on `https://github.com/abroer/jsltSpringLocaleProblem.git`. This maven project works correctly and is being built without errors.

The problem can be recreated by building the `https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example.git` project.

Here's the job configuration

```
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftApplicationUUIDJobProperty plugin="openshift@1.4">
      <applicationUUID></applicationUUID>
    </hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftApplicationUUIDJobProperty>
    <hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftBuilderSizeJobProperty plugin="openshift@1.4">
      <builderSize>small</builderSize>
    </hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftBuilderSizeJobProperty>
    <hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftBuilderTimeoutJobProperty plugin="openshift@1.4">
      <builderTimeout>300000</builderTimeout>
    </hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftBuilderTimeoutJobProperty>
    <hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftBuilderTypeJobProperty plugin="openshift@1.4">
      <builderType></builderType>
    </hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftBuilderTypeJobProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@1.1.12">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <name>origin</name>
        <refspec>+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*</refspec>
        <url>https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example.git</url>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>**</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <recursiveSubmodules>false</recursiveSubmodules>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <authorOrCommitter>false</authorOrCommitter>
    <clean>false</clean>
    <wipeOutWorkspace>false</wipeOutWorkspace>
    <pruneBranches>false</pruneBranches>
    <remotePoll>false</remotePoll>
    <buildChooser class="hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser"/>
    <gitTool>Default</gitTool>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <relativeTargetDir></relativeTargetDir>
    <excludedRegions></excludedRegions>
    <excludedUsers></excludedUsers>
    <gitConfigName></gitConfigName>
    <gitConfigEmail></gitConfigEmail>
    <skipTag>false</skipTag>
    <scmName></scmName>
  </scm>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers class="vector"/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Maven>
      <targets>clean package</targets>
      <mavenName>(Default)</mavenName>
      <usePrivateRepository>false</usePrivateRepository>
      <settings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultSettingsProvider"/>
      <globalSettings class="jenkins.mvn.DefaultGlobalSettingsProvider"/>
    </hudson.tasks.Maven>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Comment: This seems like a permissions issue.  Try to figure out where it is trying to write the user preferences, and change the directory to include write permissions for whatever user is running the process.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, these messages shouldn't fail the compilation.

GWT uses preferences only in one place: update checks, so store when it last checked for updates. This is done asynchronously in a dedicated thread, and shouldn't fail the build.

GWT supports disabling update checks by passing the `-XdisableUpdateCheck` to the `Compiler`, but the `gwt-maven-plugin` doesn't let you do it. Try using the `exec-maven-plugin` to call the GWT compiler and pass the `-XdisableUpdateCheck` as argument to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: fixed compilation on my OpenShift gear as well.